# What's the name of this tag? <%=WHATEVER%>

Tags: javascript, typescript

If this is a dupe, please link me to what it's a dupe of, because I can't find the answer:

what is the name of this tag: <%= %>

It's come up in md, js, ts files and I'm not good enough with node or javascript to know the name of it.

EDITED TO CORRECT THE TAG I MIS-TYPED.

Comment: Show the code examples with this tag

Comment: Looks like jsp.

Comment: @JonasWilms don't ejs tags look like <%= %>?

Comment: it is a Embedded JavaScript (EJS)  http://www.embeddedjs.com/getting_started.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you have shown, `<%= =>` is incorrect, but it most closely resembles a JSP expression `<%= scripting-language-expression %>`.

From: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaov.html.

> A JSP expression is used to insert the value of a scripting language
>   expression, converted into a string, into the data stream returned to
>   the client. When the scripting language is the Java programming
>   language, an expression is transformed into a statement that converts
>   the value of the expression into a String object and inserts it into
>   the implicit out object.
>
> The syntax for an expression is as follows:
>
> ```
> <%= scripting-language-expression %>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It is referer for any code from the libraries that added to javascript such as Embedded JavaScript (EJS).
http://www.embeddedjs.com/getting_started.html